# allow time picker in BsDatepickerConfig

Tags: html, angular, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using BsDatepickerConfig to pick date also I want to use it to pick time in same field is there any way?

```
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <fieldset [disabled]="caseFound">
        <div class="ui-input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" #dp="bsDatepicker" bsDatepicker
         bsConfig]="bsConfig" formControlName="cardExpiryDate" placeholder='DD-MM-YYYY'
         (ngModelChange)="triggerCheck()">
          <span class="input-bar"></span>
          <label>Card Expiry Date <span class="mdtr">*</span></label>
          <span *ngIf="submitted && f.cardExpiryDate.errors" class="tooltiptext">{{'Card Expiry Date is required'}}</span>
           </div>
        </fieldset>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `withTimepicker` as `true` in `bsconfig`:

```html
    [bsConfig]="{withTimepicker: true, rangeInputFormat : 'MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a', dateInputFormat: 'MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'}"
```

[Example](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/datepicker?tab=overview#with-timepicker) from documentation.

`withTimepicker` config option was added in ngx-bootstrap `v7.1.2`

Comment: I have copy same code but still doesn't show time picker, is there specific version of angular accept  withTimepicker !!

Comment: @Hamda which version of Angular and ngx-bootstrap are you using?

Comment: I'm using 8 version @Siddhant

Comment: @Hamda The `withTimepicker` option was added in ngx-bootstrap `7.1.2` version